# XamlCompiler error WMC0055: Cannot assign text value '10.0' into property 'xx' of type 'Decimal'

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app

I want to add a staticresource to my UWP XAML code as below:

```
<Page
x:Class="Appnap.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Appnap"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<Page.Resources>
    <local:MyCoffee CoffeeName="Esperso" Price="10.0" x:Key="okkk">
    </local:MyCoffee>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <TextBlock Name="test" Text="{Binding CoffeeName,Source={StaticResource okkk}}" Margin="155,150,-155,-150" />   
</Grid>
```

I also added coffee class as below:

```
namespace Appnap
{
    public partial class MyCoffee
    {
        public string CoffeeName { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When I try to compile my code, i get the error that the value cannot be assigned to price (XamlCompiler error WMC0055: Cannot assign text value '10.0' into property 'Price' of type 'Decimal')
I tried: 10, 10.0 and 10M but nothing changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the XamlCompiler error said, the problem here is that XamlCompiler can't convert text value '10.0' into `Decimal`.

In UWP XAML, it uses a feature called a Type Converter to perform a conversion to turn string value into a strongly typed version of that value. A Type Converter is simply a class that has one function, and that is to translate a string value 
into a strong type. And there are several of these that are built into the Universal Windows Platform API. For more information, please see: [UWP-005 - Understanding Type Converters](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-10-development-for-absolute-beginners/UWP-005-Understanding-Type-Converters).

However, Type Converter for `Decimal` is not in the build-in UWP API. XamlCompiler can't parse the value you've set in XAML into `decimal`. In WPF, we can use `TypeConverter` class to create our own TypeConverter for the unsupported ones. But this is not supported in UWP.

As a workaround, you can initialize `MyCoffee` in code-behind and using `Binding` in XAML like following:

In code-behind, set `DataContext` for the page or the TextBlock

```cs
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    //Set DataContext for the page
    this.DataContext = new MyCoffee { CoffeeName = "Esperso", Price = 10M };
    //Or for the TextBlock
    //test.DataContext = new MyCoffee { CoffeeName = "Esperso", Price = 10M };
}
```

And in XAML, using

```
<TextBlock Name="test" Margin="155,150,-155,-150" Text="{Binding CoffeeName}" />
```

This is the commonest way we used for binding.

But if you do want to use `MyCoffee` as a `StaticResource`, you can set `Price`'s type to `double` which is supported by existing Type Converters. However this may lose some accuracy of the price, it depends on your specific data.

Comment: i know it's an old thread, but what if you wanna use into xaml <Custom:DataClass Price="12.45"/> ? compile error : cannot assign text value "12.45" into property Price of type Decimal... i don't wanna change my classes for design purpose...

Comment: @cyrianox I'm facing exactly the same problem. Have you found a solution for this in the meantime?

Comment: @DominicJonas sorry, too old for me (5 years ago). As far as i remember, i used code converters

Answer (score 1):

Use the IValueConverter, create a new class and implement the IValueConverter, select the created value converter when you are binding to this property.